# Core Data - Are primitive setters / getters faster? When not to use?

Tags: core-data

From Apple's Core Data Programming Guide:

> Core Data dynamically generates efficient public and primitive get and
> set attribute accessor methods and relationship accessor methods for
> managed object classes.
>
> ...
>
> Primitive accessor methods are similar to "normal" or public key-value
> coding compliant accessor methods, except that Core Data uses them as
> the most basic data methods to access data, consequently they do not
> issue key-value access or observing notifications. Put another way,
> they are to primitiveValueForKey: and setPrimitiveValue:forKey: what
> public accessor methods are to valueForKey: and setValue:forKey:.

I would then expect the primitive accessor methods to be better performant then the public accessors because they do not trigger KVO notifications. Is there a way to effectively test this theory with Time Profiler? (Surely it can't be as easy as putting the two call in their own for-loops that iterate a zillion times and compare the results...)

Obviously the primitive accessors aren't to be called by objects or functions outside of the Managed Object subclass, but when shouldn't you use them from within the class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edelaney05,

As you appear to know, Core Data depends upon the KVC/KVO features of Objective-C. Yes, you are correct that the path length is slightly longer through the accessors. What of it? Performance of Core Data is dominated by the performance of the I/O subsystem.

IOW, tuning your fetch request is much more important than avoiding the accessor overhead. Can you do what you're proposing? Yes. Should you? No. You should, IMO, focus upon how to get your data into a MOC efficiently and then refine it with predicates and other filter techniques. Learning how to use the various key path operators and predicate language after the fetch is very important to writing performant CD code. Only after Instruments can document that you are spending an appreciable amount of time in the accessors would I consider your strategy of avoiding them.

In answer to your specific question, you should generally restrict your use of the primitive accessors to within your reimplementation of the public accessors. Sticking with accessors for all of your code then becomes your standard pattern. This gives you the long term engineering benefit of having the ability to associate arbitrary behavior with any property. Finally, if you can use the various key path and set operators, then the CD team has already optimized those access patterns. They are quite performant.

Andrew

Comment: Based on your answer, it seem this questions falls into the same line of thinking as "Within an NSObject subclass shouldn't I access instance variables directly instead of using their get/set methods because it's faster?" My takeaway is there are larger, easier, and smarter performance gains elsewhere - a thought that hadn't crossed my mind as I typed up the question ;-)

Comment: edelaney05, I apologize if I have offended you. That said, my point stands and it stands the same way for ivars. Just because you can access them doesn't mean it is good practice to do so. That is part of why Objective-C no longer requires that you declare them. They are subtly encouraging you to ignore them. Andrew

Comment: I'm not offended at all! I am absolutely in agreement with you regarding direct ivar access of an NSObject subclass, and just hadn't considered the parallel with primitives and NSManagedObject.